# Kali nethunter installation error on android using Termux (404 not found)

Tags: software-installation, android

I was trying to install kali nethunter on my android mobile (android 13) and when i ran the

`./install-nethunter-termux`

command, I got the following response :

```
--2023-09-25 13:33:06--  https://kali.download/nethunter-images/current/rootfs/kalifs-arm64-full.tar.xz
Resolving kali.download (kali.download)... 104.18.103.100, 104.18.102.100, 2606:4700:9640:38fb:330c:6:6812:6664
Connecting to kali.download (kali.download)|104.18.103.100|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2023-09-25 13:33:09 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

I don't understand what this error means and so I seek help with this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I respectfully suggest that if you do not know how to read this error, which really is as clear as it gets ("not found"), you probably shouldn't be installing tools like `nethunter` yet. Take some time to learn some basic networking first. You need to learn to walk before learning to run.

Comment: As far as I can see, the file is available in the location that your script tried to access. You might have had a simple case of bad luck, hitting the exact time when the files were updated. Try again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## UPDATE (because of below comments)

---

Firstly, **the error 404** means that the resource could not be found (probably doesn't exist). See [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=error+404+meaning&oq=&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqCQgEEEUYOxjCAzIJCAAQRRg7GMIDMgkIARBFGDsYwgMyCQgCEEUYOxjCAzIJCAMQRRg7GMIDMgkIBBBFGDsYwgMyCQgFEEUYOxjCAzIJCAYQRRg7GMIDMgkIBxBFGDsYwgMyCQgIEEUYOxjCAzIJCAkQRRg7GMIDMgkIChBFGDsYwgMyCQgLEEUYOxjCAzIJCAwQRRg7GMIDMgkIDRBFGDsYwgMyCQgOEEUYOxjCAzIPCA8QLhgDGI8BGLQCGOoCMhEIEBAAGAMYQhiPARi0AhjqAjIRCBEQABgDGEIYjwEYtAIY6gIyEQgSEAAYAxhCGI8BGLQCGOoCMg8IExAuGAMYjwEYtAIY6gLSAQYtMWowajioAhSwAgE&client=tablet-android-hmd-rvo3&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) for more information.

The reason for this error is that **kali nethunter changed the download links to their rootfs**.

I recently came across the same issue (when using [my installer script](https://github.com/jorexdeveloper/termux-nethunter)), but then i modified it to work with the changes.

## SOLUTION

Below are the steps to work around this issue.

1. Download the **rootfs for your system** [here](https://kali.download/nethunter-images/current/rootfs/)
2. Extract the rootfs (.zip) with `unzip`
3. Extract the rootfs archive inside (.tar.xz) with `tar xf`
4. Now use `proot` command to launch nethunter. See proot(1) (with `man proot` for how to use it)
5. If you are successful, you may want to fix some issues with the rootfs like **setting root password**, granting sudo access to user **kali**, etc

## ALTERNATIVE

The script below automates the installation proces, **but** its not from an official source (its **made and updated by me**), so **use it with that in mind**

It is fully documented [here](https://github.com/jorexdeveloper/termux-nethunter) but you can copy and paste the below commands in Termux to download **and show its help information** (not run it directly)

```bash
apt-get update -y && apt-get install wget -y && wget -O install-nethunter.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jorexdeveloper/termux-nethunter/main/install-nethunter.sh && bash install-nethunter.sh -h
```

As we all wait for the official updated script from kali nethunter, we may try follow above steps for a manual installation in Termux.

### COMMENT

Its also worth noting that downloading the rootfs manually and attempting to use the old installer may not work because it performs a **shasum check** and will fail to verify its integrity

Answer (score 2):

You will receive an HTTP status code in response to your request to the kali.download server, which you can use for troubleshooting.

In this case it is the code 404, which means that the requested file does not exist.

Explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404

Probably the download link has simply changed. You should be able to find the correct file here:

https://build.nethunter.com/kalifs/kalifs-latest/

I found this link by searching for the package name (kalifs-arm64-full.tar.xz) via Google.

Comment: Note that the URL mentioned in the error message seems to be correct and that if the user tries again, it will most likely work.

Answer (score -2):

1. Install the [Kali NetHunter App Store app](https://store.nethunter.com/).
2. From the NetHunter App Store, install Termux, then enter the following commands:

   ```shell
   termux-setup-storage
   pkg install wget
   wget -O install-nethunter-termux https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/nethunter/build-scripts/kali-nethunter-project/raw/master/nethunter-rootless/install-nethunter-termux
   chmod +x install-nethunter-termux
   ./install-nethunter-termux
   ```

Comment: I got an error on the last command (404 not found). I tried manually downloading the kalifs-arm64-full.tar.xz file but it didn't do anything to fix it.

Comment: @CapHimYT Downloading it manually is less likely to fix the error...i have inspected some few installer scripts and they seem to perform a shasum check..just use an updated script [here](https://github.com/jorexdeveloper/termux-nethunter)